# Lebesgue measure and counting measure are not interchangeable while integrating

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $D=\{(x,x):x\in[0,1]\} \subset [0,1]^2$ and $\mu$ and $v$ be the Lebesgue measure and the counting measure on $[0,1]$ respectively.

Show that $\int\int1_D(x,y) d\mu(x)dv(x) \neq \int\int1_D(x,y)dv(y)d\mu(x)$.

$1_D$ denotes the characteristic function.

May someone give me an explanation as to why those two integrals are not the same? I also need to answer if this contradicts the theorem of Fubini/Tonelli? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calculating the integrals? If you did try and somehow got stuck, then please inform us in which part you are having trouble. For the final part of the question, you need to consider wheter the measures are actually $\sigma$-finite, since this is a requirement for applying the Fubini/Tonelli theorem.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my last question. I'm actually stuck at calculating the integrals as I don't know how to evaluate these.

Comment: Note that on $[0,1]^2$ we have: $$1_D(x,y)=1_{\{y\}}(x)=1_{\{x\}}(y)$$Substituting this might make the integration more obvious

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any fixed $y \in [0,1]$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int 1_D(x,y) \: d\mu(x) &= \mu(\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \: | \: (x,y) \in D \}) \\
                         &= \mu(\{y\}) \\
                         &=  0.
\end{align*}
On the other hand we have for any fixed $x \in [0,1]$ that
\begin{align*}
\int 1_D(x,y) \: d\nu(y) &= \nu(\{ y \in \mathbb{R} \: | \: (x,y) \in D \}) \\
                         &= \nu(\{x\}) \\
                         &=  1.
\end{align*}
This means that
$$\int \int 1_D(x,y) \: d\mu(x)d\nu(y) = \int 0 \: d\nu(y) = 0,$$
while
$$\int \int 1_D(x,y) \: d\nu(y)d\mu(x) = \int 1 \: d\mu(x) = 1,$$
from which we conclude that the integrals are indeed different. This is however not a contradiction, since $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.